# Wrong GLIBCXX version when running a program that was compiled on the same machine

Tags: c++, cmake, libstdc++

How is it possible that a program that I compile, link and run on the same machine to have GLIBCXX version errors when I try to run it? Does anyone know?

Here is the error I am getting:

```
0.01s$ build/test/gamgee_test
build/test/gamgee_test: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by build/test/gamgee_test)
build/test/gamgee_test: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by build/test/gamgee_test)
```

full output (with VERBOSE=1) including building and running is here:
https://travis-ci.org/broadinstitute/gamgee/jobs/39751787

This wasn't happening before, only after I switched to cmake. Also the same code runs fine with Clang (using a bundled version of libstdc++ since I haven't installed libc++ on the VM). That log is here: https://travis-ci.org/broadinstitute/gamgee/jobs/39751786

very puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime paths are different to compile paths. Sounds like you have more than one version of your libraries on your system. check your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable and call your executable with ldd to see what libraries it is using/trying to use.

Comment: how can I check the runtime and compile library paths distinctly? I thought that `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH` was telling me the search paths for both compile and runtime.

Comment: you were right, there was a second libstdc++ installed from gcc 4.6. After much juggling I was able to replace it with the 4.9.1 stdlibc++ by linking it from /usr/lib64. This was the only way I could fool travis (since I can't ad /usr/lib64 to ld.so.conf).